# How to get values of a two contact forms which is in two separate tabs in php?

Tags: php

I have a contact form in php which has has two tabs containing two different contact forms. I want to get all the values of both the forms and send it as an email. I have coded it for one of the tab, but i am not getting the values of each of the field in the contact form in that tab. Can anyone tell how to do this ? My code is shown below for one of the tab:

```
  <form name="contactForm" id='contact_form' method="post" action=''>

   <div tab-id="1" class="tab active"> 



        <div class="form-inline">
          <div class="form-group col-sm-12 padd">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="exampleInputName" placeholder="name" >
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-sm-12 padd">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="exampleInputEmail" placeholder="email address">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-sm-12 padd">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telephone" placeholder="phone">
          </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-12 padd">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Country" id="exampleInputName" placeholder="Country" >
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-sm-12 padd">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="3" id="exampleInputMessage" placeholder="message" ></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 padd">
          <div id='mail_success' class='success' style="display:none;">Your message has been sent successfully.
          </div><!-- success message -->
          <div id='mail_fail' class='error' style="display:none;"> Sorry, error occured this time sending your message.
          </div><!-- error message -->
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-8 padd">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcJqyITAAAAABks5hnD6U_2ptu09RiXYOHvNNud"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-sm-4 padd" id='submit'>
          <input type="submit" id='send_message' name="send" class="btn  btn-lg costom-btn" value="send">
        </div>



  </div>
<div tab-id="2" class="tab">

        <div class="form-inline">
          <div class="form-group col-sm-12 padd">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="exampleInputName" placeholder="full name" >
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-sm-6 padd">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="exampleInputEmail" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 pad">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telephone" placeholder="Phone">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-sm-12 padd">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="exampleInputSubject" placeholder="Tell us about your project in your own words ?" >
          </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-12 padd">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="exampleInputSubject" placeholder="Tell us about you or your company" >
          </div>

            <div class="form-group col-sm-12 padd">
                <p>Which services are you interested in ?</p>

              <p>
                <input type="checkbox" id="test1" />
                <label for="test1"></label>
              </p>

             <p>
                <input type="checkbox" id="test2"/>
                <label for="test2"></label>
              </p>
                <p>
                <input type="checkbox" id="test3"/>
                <label for="test3"></label>
              </p>
                <p>
                <input type="checkbox" id="test4"/>
                <label for="test4"></label>
              </p>
                <p>
                <input type="checkbox" id="test5"/>
                <label for="test5"></label>
              </p>
                <p>
                <input type="checkbox" id="test6"/>
                <label for="test6"></label>
              </p>


            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
          <div id='mail_success' class='success' style="display:none;">Your message has been sent successfully.
          </div><!-- success message -->
          <div id='mail_fail' class='error' style="display:none;"> Sorry, error occured this time sending your message.
          </div><!-- error message -->
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12" id='submit'>
          <input type="submit" id='send_message' class="btn  btn-lg costom-btn" value="send">
        </div>

  </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Please use single <form> for entire page.

Comment: all tabs are place inside form

Comment: all tabs should be inside a single form tag ?

Comment: Yeah ... One form tag.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this code.

```
<form name="contactForm" id='contact_form' method="post" action='php/email.php'>

  //This is the first tab
  <div tab-id="1" class="tab active"> 
    <div class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group col-sm-12 padd">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="exampleInputName" placeholder="name" >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-12 padd">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="exampleInputEmail" placeholder="email address">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-12 padd">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telephone" placeholder="phone">
      </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12 padd">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Country" id="exampleInputName" placeholder="Country" >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-12 padd">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="3" id="exampleInputMessage" placeholder="message" ></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 padd">
      <div id='mail_success' class='success' style="display:none;">Your message has been sent successfully.
      </div><!-- success message -->
      <div id='mail_fail' class='error' style="display:none;"> Sorry, error occured this time sending your message.
      </div><!-- error message -->
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-8 padd">
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcJqyITAAAAABks5hnD6U_2ptu09RiXYOHvNNud"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4 padd" id='submit'>
      <input type="submit" id='send_message' name="send" class="btn  btn-lg costom-btn" value="send">
    </div>
  </div>

  //This is the Second tab
 <div tab-id="2" class="tab">
    <div class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group col-sm-12 padd">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="exampleInputName" placeholder="full name" >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-6 padd">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="exampleInputEmail" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-6 pad">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telephone" placeholder="Phone">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-12 padd">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="exampleInputSubject" placeholder="Tell us about your project in your own words ?" >
      </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12 padd">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="exampleInputSubject" placeholder="Tell us about you or your company" >
      </div>

        <div class="form-group col-sm-12 padd">
            <p>Which services are you interested in ?</p>
            <form action="#">
          <p>
            <input type="checkbox" id="test1" />
            <label for="test1">Web Design &amp; development</label>
          </p>

         <p>
            <input type="checkbox" id="test2"/>
            <label for="test2">E-Commerce Solutions</label>
          </p>
            <p>
            <input type="checkbox" id="test3"/>
            <label for="test3">Digital Marketing</label>
          </p>
            <p>
            <input type="checkbox" id="test4"/>
            <label for="test4">SEO Solutions</label>
          </p>
            <p>
            <input type="checkbox" id="test5"/>
            <label for="test5">2D&amp;3D Animation</label>
          </p>
            <p>
            <input type="checkbox" id="test6"/>
            <label for="test6">Game development</label>
          </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
      <div id='mail_success' class='success' style="display:none;">Your message has been sent successfully.
      </div><!-- success message -->
      <div id='mail_fail' class='error' style="display:none;"> Sorry, error occured this time sending your message.
      </div><!-- error message -->
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-12" id='submit'>
      <input type="submit" id='send_message' class="btn  btn-lg costom-btn" value="send">
    </div>
  </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: <?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['send']))
{
 echo 'send';exit;
 
}?>

Comment: I have added this code on the top of your code.but it is not displaying the mesage send.

Comment: For those message you have to try php code.. if send successfully then set the session variable . after set you should display over there..

Comment: Is your form post all filed in submit?

Comment: sss..I have filled all the input fields

Comment: actually when i am clicking the send button it should go to the php code written on the top..right ?

Comment: Yeah..with condition like this .<?php if(isset($_POST['send'])) { echo 'send';exit; }?>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following form-tab html structure:

```
<form name="contactForm" id='contact_form' method="post" action=''>
   <div tab-id="1" class="tab active">
     ...
     <input name="field1" value="" class="form-control" />
     <input name="field2" value="" class="form-control" />
   </div>
   <div tab-id="2" class="tab">
     ...
     <input name="field1" value="" class="form-control" />
     <input name="field2" value="" class="form-control" />
   </div>
</form>
```

As your div tabs have not attribute called **id**, and the **class** attribute you assigned is the same for every tab, it is not clear to see how to define the [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info) selector for the inputs within those tabs you created.

You can access the values of each tab, using [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info) as follows:

```
var fields = {}
fields.tab1 = {}

fields.tab1.field1 = $('div[tab-id=1] input[name=field1]').val()
fields.tab1.field2 = $('div[tab-id=1] input[name=field2]').val()

fields.tab2 = {}

fields.tab2.field1 = $('div[tab-id=2] input[name=field1]').val()
fields.tab2.field2 = $('div[tab-id=2] input[name=field2]').val()
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c5y3uz1j/) of the working example.

Answer (score 0):

```
var datastring = $("#contact_form").serialize();
alert(datastring);
```

try this in jquery after , you wiil get all the elements values between the 
...

here data strings gives output as below

***name=tj&email=tj@gmail.com&telephone=8888888888&Country=ind&message=msdfdf&name=tj&email=tj@gmail.com&telephone=12345689&subject=sub&subject=sub***

Comment: but I want to send these values as a mail to a email-id.

Comment: you can send this values in ajax call  as GET / POST method and the you can access in php page.

Comment: Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: `var datastring = $("#contact_form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "your url.php",
            data: datastring,
            success: function(data) {
                 alert('Data send');
            }
        });`